# Is it possible to javascript (PWA) detect fake gps / mock gps?

Tags: javascript, angular, gps, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA application to get absence location, I need method to avoid user using Fake Location tools. Is any method / package on javascript to detect installed Fake gps on the phone?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible for *any* software to reliably detect fake or mocked GPS, PWA or otherwise.

You can use heuristics to make sure the data seems reasonable before accepting it... that's about it.